# How to compute a conditional percentile in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, benchmarking, percentile

I'm currently working with Oracle SQL and I need a logic to extract a particular benchmark value from a data set.

**What I have:**

```
Article | Sales
1       | 5
2       | 0
3       | 2
4       | 9
........| ......
119     | 3
120     | 8
121     | 12
```

**What I need:**
I'm looking for the top 5% percent of the articles and in particular the worst selling one of that set. In order to continue my analysis, I would need the sales amount from that article next to the existing columns.

Assuming that the top 5% of articles sell 9, 12, 14, 14, 17 and 19 times (with 9 being the worst of the top 5%), the table would need to look like this:

```
Article | Sales | Benchmark
1       | 5     | 9
2       | 0     | 9
3       | 2     | 9
4       | 9     | 9
........| ......| ......
118     | 3     | 9
119     | 8     | 9
120     | 12    | 9
```

Any advice on how i can accomplish that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `percentile_cont()` or `percentile_disc()`.  However, I often do this type of calculation manually:

```
  select t.*,
         min(case when seqnum >= cnt * 19 / 20 then sales end) over () as benchmark
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (order by sales) as seqnum,
               count(*) over () as cnt
        from t
       ) t;
```

Comment: Why do it manually and not with `percentile_disc()`? Have you found it to behave incorrectly? Otherwise it would surely be more efficient and easier to read and maintain. And it should be included in the answer along with the manual computation.